# "this is undefined" TypeError using FullCalendar with Flatpickr in Rails/Webpacker env

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, webpacker, flatpickr

I have a page with a FullCalendar instance (listing orders per day on the calendar). When the user clicks the day it loads a partial of that days orders information. Inside of the partial with order information, there is a link which pops up a modal with a table including more information and options for each order. One of the options is a "receipt" making tool which uses the "FlatPickr" library for a date selection input. When the popup loads this receipt partial (including js for FlatPickr) it breaks the "dateclick" callback for FullCalendar (the links don't work). In console, I'm getting

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined
>
> fp_incr rakuten_orders line 5419 > injectedScript:2052
> jQuery 4
> dateClick fullcalendar.js:315
> ```

etc.

And I get a routing error for the maped js file

> Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
> Resource URL: null
> Source Map URL: datetimepicker-e769115066d0a3757f8e.js.map

When I remove the flatpickr pack tag `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'datetimepicker', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` from the receipt partial, all is well. But, of course, the date input no longer has FlatPickr.

The FullCalendar implementation for this particular page is:

```js
 var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
locale: 'ja',
contentHeight: 450,
aspectRatio: 1,
headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear',
    center: '',
    right: 'title'
},
customButtons: {
},
selectable: true,
events: '/rakuten_orders.json',
eventClick: function(info) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/fetch_rakuten_orders_list/' + encodeURI(moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
        dataType: "script",
        data: info.event.start
    });
},
dateClick: function(info) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/fetch_rakuten_orders_list/' + encodeURI(moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
        dataType: "script",
        data: info.date
    });
},
loading: function (loading) {
    if (loading) {
        $(calendarEl).prepend( calendar_load );
    } else {
        $('.loading_overlay').remove()
    }
}
});
};
```

The error appears to be with line 315, where an ajax call is used to load the partial with the date data from the date the user clicked.

Here's the FlatPickr implementation

```js
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
window.flatpickr = flatpickr
import { Japanese } from "flatpickr/dist/l10n/ja.js"

$('.datepicker').flatpickr({
        "locale": Japanese,
        enableTime: false,
        dateFormat: "Y年m月d日",
        monthSelectorType: 'static',
    }
);
```

Is there some way I should change either implementation to not conflict? Is my reasoning for the source of the error correct?

If I have no response I may try to just use another instance of FullCalendar instead of FlatPickr in these specific situations (avoiding FlatPickr). Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I tried to implement the suggest to switch from $.ajax to fetch()

Here's what that (super simple implementation) looks like:

```js
    async function fetchByDate(url, date) {
        var requestUrl = url + encodeURI(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

        return await fetch(requestUrl,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: {
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                response.json()
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

and

```js
        var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
            locale: 'ja',
            contentHeight: 450,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear',
                center: '',
                right: 'title'
            },
            customButtons: {
            },
            selectable: true,
            events: '/rakuten_orders.json',
            eventClick: function(info) {
                // $.ajax({
                //  type: "GET",
                //  url: '/fetch_rakuten_orders_list/' + encodeURI(moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
                //  dataType: "script",
                //  data: info.event.start
                // });
            },
            dateClick: function(info) {
                fetchByDate('/fetch_rakuten_orders_list/', info.date)
                // $.ajax({
                //  type: "GET",
                //  url: '/fetch_rakuten_orders_list/' + encodeURI(moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
                //  dataType: "script",
                //  data: info.date
                // });

            },
            loading: function (loading) {
                if (loading) {
                    $(calendarEl).prepend( calendar_load );
                } else {
                    $('.loading_overlay').remove()
                }
            }
        });
```

When I click on the date, I get a `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` in the console, for the following js.erb file:

```
$("#partial").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'daily_orders', locals: { daily_orders: @daily_orders }, remote: true ) %>");
```

Comment: `this` is a `new` instance of a constructor or class, which becomes an Object when you call `new` on it, or an Object literal *(which is a new instance)*. In the method of an instance `this` refers to the Object to which it is a property of... yes, that includes an Event Listener.

Comment: `$.ajax({` seems to be the problem, but I'm not sure of another way to implement it...or is the error referring to that line because of something _inside_ the included function (like the "info.date" variable), perhaps? The Object here I guess is referred to as "info" by FullCalendar? This is why I was thinking there must be some conflict between some Flatpickr "date" Object and this part of the FullCalendar "dateclick" handler.

Comment: Another thought I had was, maybe when the Bootstrap modal "close" event tiggers, I could "update" (or delete and refresh) the calendar--I tried that and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `$.ajax({ seems to be the problem, but I'm not sure of another way to implement it` ...why not use `fetch()`?

Comment: @ADyson Have never used fetch() before (I'm a novice with JS). It seems to me that jquery isn't working with fetch() when loading partials? so I have to set up vanilla js html replacement scripts for every single partial that I want to load with this method (or set up some kind of template to include), surely there must be an easier way.

Comment: I'm not saying you _have_ to, but if you're saying that $.ajax is causing you some sort of conflict, then fetch() is the native alternative to the $.ajax command, that's all. You maybe only could try replacing it in the place where you're having a problem. If you haven't used fetch() before don't worry, there are many tutorials online, and good documentation on MDN.

Comment: Anyway it looks like you tried to do it, which is great. The error seems odd. Are you sure it comes from that line? It seems unconnected with what you've changed. If I had to guess I'd say it was from `.then((response) => {
                response.json()
            })` - in your $.ajax version you didn't try to process the response from this request, but now you're trying to parse it as JSON. If the response is empty, or it isn't JSON, then you'd get exactly the error you've mentioned. It's not clear why you added that part to the fetch() command.